# What is the pythonic way of running an asyncio event loop forever?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) it seems the recommended way to kickstart a asyncio application is to use `asyncio.run()`, so my application looks like this:

```py
async def async_main():
    # Everything here can use asyncio.create_task():
    o = ObjectThatMustBeKeptReferenced()
    create_tasks_and_register_callbacks(o)

    # Wait forever, ugly:
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10000)

asyncio.run(async_main())
```

This infinite loop at the end of `async_main()` feels very wrong. In other languages, there is where I would call the event loop forever. So I tried this:

```py
def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    # Everything here can use asyncio.create_task():
    o = ObjectThatMustBeKeptReferenced()
    create_tasks_and_register_callbacks(o)

    # Wait forever, pretty:
    loop.run_forever()

main()
```

The problem here is this will fail with an error of the sorts `RuntimeError: no running event loop` when I call `asyncio.create_task()` inside my functions, even though the event loop is created and registered on the thread.

What is the pythonic, one way of sleeping forever on the `asyncio` event loop?

Comment: are the tasks and callbacks infinitely running? If yes then why do you need your own infinite loop? If no then why do you want it to run indefinitely?

Comment: Yes, there are. I don't need my own loop, I just can't exit the function, otherwise `asyncio.run()` returns, my program exits and the infinite tasks are no longer scheduled.

Comment: I understand now, I was thinking the equivalent of `asyncio.gather` was done implicitly but obviously isn't by `asyncio.run`, maybe I was thinking of calling `asyncio.async(async_main())` then do a run forever but I haven't used python async in a while. explicitly calling `gather` seems like the best option to me.

Comment: `asyncio.async()` ? Maybe you mistyped, because there is no such function.

Comment: I posted an answer to address [how old `async` is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65684730/what-is-the-pythonic-way-of-running-an-asyncio-event-loop-forever/65723545#comment116178710_65684730) and [exposing the created tasks probably should be a feature not a hole in the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65684730/what-is-the-pythonic-way-of-running-an-asyncio-event-loop-forever/65723545#comment116164396_65688291)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply change the `sleep` loop to an ad-hoc event which is never set:

```
# wait forever
await asyncio.Event().wait()
```

If needed, you can easily modify this to store the event into a variable and propagate it as a shutdown signal.

Another option is for your function that creates the tasks to *return* the tasks it has created, in which case you can await them even though (or precisely because) they'll never complete:

```
async def async_main():
    o = ObjectThatMustBeKeptReferenced()
    tasks = create_tasks_and_register_callbacks(o)
    # wait forever, or until a task raises
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

While this doesn't communicate the intention of looping forever as clearly, it has the advantage that it will halt the program (and propagate the exception to the code that calls `asyncio.run(async_main())`) if any of the tasks raises an unhandled exception.

Comment: Nice! Seems so obvious now! BTW, I went with a `await asyncio.Future()` instead of using `Event` because it is a more lightweight object.

Comment: It is even a little poetic: wait for the future! Obviously, it will never arrive...

Comment: @lvella You're correct that a future is more lightweight and spot-on about the poeticness. :) The weight of an event shouldn't matter because you only create it once. If you're using a future, consider creating it with `loop.create_future()` in order to accommodate alternative event loops such as uvloop. To me `await asyncio.get_event_loop().create_future()` seems a tiny bit more obscure than `await asyncio.Event().wait()` because event is a high-level construct that is easier to understand than a future, but that may be a matter of taste.

Comment: @lvella Another option is to just await the tasks you've created, despite them never halting. I've updated the answer to mention it.

Comment: I don't like the design implications of waiting on one of the tasks, because they are hidden and well isolated inside their respective classes, and getting them back would be a hole in the API.

Comment: @lvella Fair enough. I'll leave the suggestion in the answer, though, because it makes sense in other contexts.

Answer (score 5):

Infinite `while True` is quite pythonic for `asyncio`-based scripts. It represents *main* loop of your program. This decouples script logic from low-level *event loop* and allows you to control the lifecycle of the program from the point of view of the application logic. Do some periodic actions and checkings.

Such loops wrapped in a `try-except` or `finally` can be placed in other modules and classes, which imply long-term periodic work. This is all consistent with `asyncio` as it uses *cooperative multitasking* and such loops give control to the `event loop` (e.g. by means of `await asyncio.sleep`).

`asyncio.run` is more preferable, because it still boils down to the calling of `run_forever`, but when exiting the main coroutine of the script, it cancels and clears running tasks, asynchronous generators, etc.

Real-world examples of infinite loops:

[Uvicorn](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/server.py)

```
    #...
    async def main_loop(self):
        counter = 0
        should_exit = await self.on_tick(counter)
        while not should_exit:
            counter += 1
            counter = counter % 864000
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            should_exit = await self.on_tick(counter)
```

[aiohttp](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/master/aiohttp/web.py):

```
        #...
        # sleep forever by 1 hour intervals,
        # on Windows before Python 3.8 wake up every 1 second to handle
        # Ctrl+C smoothly
        if sys.platform == "win32" and sys.version_info < (3, 8):
            delay = 1
        else:
            delay = 3600

        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(delay)
    finally:
        await runner.cleanup()
```

Comment: Note that sleeping for 1s will prevent the process from ever going to sleep (for more than 1s), even if the event loop has no work to do. This kind of thing is not a big deal on servers, but can drain laptop batteries.

Answer (score 3):

The way I had done this in the past was [to use `asyncio.async`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.async) which is a deprecated alias [to `asyncip.ensure_future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.ensure_future).  The biggest issue people faced was that they would call `ensure_future` without a running loop which doesn't ensure anything, so the [higher-level API `asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) was added to assert there is a running loop so that the task would actually get run.  In your case you want to schedule the `main` task **then run the loop forever** so the lower-level API of `ensure_future` is indeed what you want:

```
async def async_main():
    # Everything here can use asyncio.create_task():
    o = ObjectThatMustBeKeptReferenced()
    create_tasks_and_register_callbacks(o)
    
asyncio.ensure_future(async_main())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

this basically indicates that when the loop is running we ensure `async_main` will execute but unlike `asyncio.run` we get the loop to run forever not just until it finishes the main entry point.

---

But you can do better, whether a given task will run forever or not shouldn't matter, you should ideally keep track of them and have your function `await` on all of them, if some of them run forever then your function will run forever as well by extension, but if not then as soon as all your async tasks have exited then your program exits as well. All that would be required is to keep track of the return value of each `create_task` that is run and [pass them all to an `asyncio.gather` as @user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688291/5827215) has done.

The classes don't have to expose their spawned tasks to accomplish this, just provide a method to wait on them, this is an example to illustrate the idea:

```
class NetworkAsyncHandler():
    def __init__(self, some_data):
        # don't just create floating tasks, keep a record of them
        self._floating_coroutines = []
        self.remembered_data = some_data
        self.connect_to_some_server_idk_this_is_is_an_example("localhost")
    def connect_to_some_server_idk_this_is_is_an_example(self, host):
        # ALWAYS KEEP A REFERENCE TO THE FUTURES YOU CREATE
        a = asyncio.create_task(DO_STUFF(host, self.remembered_data))
        # assuming you were never explicitly awaiting on a yourself, then just add it to the list
        self._floating_coroutines.append(a)

    async def join(self):
        """awaits on all floating coroutines created"""
        await asyncio.gather(*self._floating_coroutines)


async def async_main():
    a = NetworkAsyncHandler("A")
    b = NetworkAsyncHandler("B")
    # this function will wait on all created subroutines and return only when all
    # sub routines end.  If some run forever then so do we.
    await asyncio.gather(a.join(), b.join())
    
# now this works exactly as you would want it to.
asyncio.run(async_main())
```

you could imagine that typically this `NetworkAsyncHandler` might run forever but maybe there is a signal it can receive from the server to shut down which causes it to return, if both servers received this signal you would want the python program to finish. The first case where you call `run_forever` this doesn't happen, in fact you don't necessarily even know if the routines are still running but in this architecture each function awaits on the routines it actually depends on and `asyncio.run` does exactly what it is intended to do.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the pythonic, one way of sleeping forever on the asyncio event loop?

`asyncio.run` is a higher level API and is typically the preferred way of running an event loop. There's nothing wrong with using the lower level `run_forever`, though.

> The problem here is this will fail with an error of the sorts `RuntimeError: no running event loop` when I call `asyncio.create_task()`

This doesn't work since `create_task` can't get the running event loop. Fortunately there is also a `create_task` method on loops. You'll need to update `create_tasks_and_register_callbacks` to accept the loop as an argument

```
def create_tasks_and_register_callbacks(obj, loop):
```

and then change any references to `asyncio.create_task` to `loop.create_task` inside its definition.