# Python asyncio sleep forever

Tags: python, python-asyncio

In some test code I simulate a request handler coroutine that never returns a response. Below works by calling `sleep` with a sufficiently large value, but a better choice would be something like `await asyncio.sleep_forever()`. Is there anything built into python asyncio that can do this?

```
async def lagging_request_handler(request):
    await asyncio.sleep(10000)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65684730/what-is-the-pythonic-way-of-running-an-asyncio-event-loop-forever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can await `asyncio.Future()` to make it run forever. It’s used in the websockets docs to serve forever: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/